# Mobile Vision in small view

Tags: android, surfaceview, barcode

I need to set [Mobile Vision barcode scanner](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-qr-codes-using-the-mobile-vision-api--cms-24680) with camera preview in small SurfaceView (1/4 of screen height). How to do it proportionally, without shrinking the camera preview?

Comment: You can find examples of video players that adjust the size of SurfaceView and TextureView to match the video aspect ratio in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika). Note in particular the use of AspectFrameLayout to modify the size of the SurfaceView. It's not clear to me from your question if that's what you want, since you talk about shrinking the preview to 1/4 height and then say you don't want to shrink the preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way.

Added camera view in my activity

```
    <com.superup.smartshelf.test.CroppedCameraPreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Created CroppedCameraPreview class

```
public class CroppedCameraPreview extends ViewGroup {

    private static final String TAG = "qwe";
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private boolean mStartRequested;
    private boolean mSurfaceAvailable;
    private CameraSource mCameraSource;
    private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;

    public CroppedCameraPreview(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
        addView(mSurfaceView);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int croppedWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int croppedHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 4;

        setMeasuredDimension(croppedWidth, croppedHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // crop view
        int actualPreviewWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int actualPreviewHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;


        if (mSurfaceView != null) {
            mSurfaceView.layout(0, 0, actualPreviewWidth, actualPreviewHeight);
        }
    }

    public void start(CameraSource cameraSource) throws IOException {
        if (cameraSource == null) {
            stop();
        }

        mCameraSource = cameraSource;

        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mStartRequested = true;
            startIfReady();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.stop();
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.release();
            mCameraSource = null;
        }
    }

    private void startIfReady() throws IOException {
        if (mStartRequested && mSurfaceAvailable) {
            mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
            /*if (mOverlay != null) {
                Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
                int min = Math.min(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                int max = Math.max(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                if (isPortraitMode()) {
                    // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated by
                    // 90 degrees
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(min, max, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                } else {
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(max, min, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                }
                mOverlay.clear();
            }*/
            mStartRequested = false;
        }
    }

    private class SurfaceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            try {
                mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            mCameraSource.stop();

        }
    }

}
```

And initialized it in my activity. `setLayoutParams` allows to set size of the view.

```
CroppedCameraPreview mPreview = (CroppedCameraPreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);

        // get display size
        final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        //set camera view on 1/4 of the screen
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels / 4);
        mPreview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).build();
    BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory(
            new BarcodeTracker.NewDetectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onNewDetection(Barcode barcode) {
                    final String rawBarcode = barcode.rawValue;
                    mPreview.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String barcode = rawBarcode;
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            mPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Log.d(TAG, barcode);

                            // do all what you want with barcode

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Barcode not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());


    mCameraSource = new CameraSource
            .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startCameraSource();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mPreview.stop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCameraSource.release();
}

private void startCameraSource() {
    try {
        mPreview.start(mCameraSource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
        mCameraSource.release();
        mCameraSource = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use imageView and put your image inside the src attribute.
This will do the trick (It has auto scaling).

Now if you want more options you can use "android:adjustViewBounds = true" and "android:scaleType".

Comment: I edited the question. I have shrinked camera preview. Need to set it in correct aspect ratio.